# How can I make sure all async_handler is finished before stop in boost::asio?

Tags: c++, boost, boost-asio

My class Reciever... It recieve some string and push it to buffer.

```
Reciever::Reciever(boost::shared_ptr<TSBuffer<std::string>> buffer, int port)
    : port(port), buffer(buffer)
{
    using namespace boost::asio;
    acceptor_ = new ip::tcp::acceptor(iosev, ip::tcp::endpoint(ip::tcp::v4(),  port));
}


Reciever::~Reciever()
{
    delete acceptor_;
}

void Reciever::run()
{
    using namespace boost::asio;
    _start();
    iosev.run();
}

void Reciever::stop()
{
    Sender s("127.0.0.1", std::string(8, '$'), port);
}

void Reciever::_start()
{
    using namespace boost::asio;
    boost::shared_ptr<ip::tcp::socket> socket(new ip::tcp::socket(iosev));
    acceptor_->async_accept(*socket, boost::bind(&Reciever::acceptHanlder, this, socket));
}

void Reciever::acceptHanlder(boost::shared_ptr<boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket> socket)
{
    std::string delim(8, '$');
    boost::system::error_code ec;
    boost::asio::streambuf strmbuf;

    boost::asio::read_until(*socket, strmbuf, delim, ec);
    std::istream is(&strmbuf);
    std::string re((std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(is)),std::istreambuf_iterator<char>());
    re.replace(re.end() - delim.size(), re.end(), "");
    if (re.size() && re != std::string(8, '$')){
        buffer->push(re);
        _start();
}
```

In main() function I use X(uncertain) threads send X strings to the Reciever. I want to stop the reciever(call the Reciever::stop) when Reciever::acceptHanlder is called X times(which means X strings is handled). 
But I don't know how to make sure that?

Comment: Why can't you count `acceptHandler` invocations?

Answer (score 2):

I see there is not possible calling **async_accept** before last line of **acceptHanlder**. So, you can simply implement a counter inside **Reciever** object and just dont call **_start** when job is done. When same **Reciever** is used in different threads, its far more complicated, i prefer to use "object for connection" paradigm.

Also you can use **asio::strand** to restrict `acceptHanlder`-s so only one `acceptHanlder` of given `Reciever` can be active at any time. This eliminates concurrency issues within `Reciever`. So you can safely call `Reciever::stop` (using same **strand**).